# Unable to update an entry in the firebase list

Tags: javascript, firebase

After few attempts, I am still unable to find the right way to update a list in firebase.

I have my dev account in firebase. But,just for this question I used the sample on the public firebase url:

```
var url1= new Firebase("https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/message_list");
url1.push({text:'Its working',user_id:'123'});
setTimeout(function (){
     url1.on('child_added', function(snap) {
     snap.update({text:'Its not working',user_id:'123'});
     snap.child('text').update('Its not working');
     console.log('messages in range', snap.val());} 
)},6000);
```

I am able to set the data, but when the child_added function is triggered for the messages. I am getting the below javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the data snapshot object correctly within your function.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/index.html

Change it to

```
snap.ref().update({text: '....', user_id: '...'});
```

If you were just looking to get the value, you'd use

```
snap.val()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike.I was struggling for nearly 2 hours.This is not clearly mentioned somehow in the firebase docs.

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.  Right now you're trying to update your snapshot(snap.update).  I'm not sure what that's for.  Instead of calling your snap, you can call your reference, url1.update.  Also, take another look at the docs for reading data, https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html  and writing data, https://www.firebase.com/docs/writing-data.html.  Looks like you've combined functions from reading and writing data.

Comment: Thanks Ron.I was not aware that snapshots are not references in turn.